# Need help setting up Torctl on Raspberry pi

Tags: networking, boot, linux, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to route all the traffic of my raspberry through the TOR network. Being completely new to Linux, I followed the first method of [this guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Route-All-Network-Traffic-Through-the-Tor-Network), I had no errors during installation but once I type `sudo torctl start` and then `sudo torctl status`, I get this :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo torctl start
--==[ torctl.sh by blackarch.org ]==--

[!] WARNING: backing up tor config
[+] backed up tor config
[*] backing up nameservers
[+] backed up nameservers
[*] backing up iptables rules
[+] backed up iptables rules
[*] backing up sysctl rules
[+] backed up sysctl rules
[!] WARNING: configuring tor
[+] configured tor
[!] WARNING: configuring nameservers
[+] configured nameservers
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
[!] WARNING: tor is not started
[*] starting tor service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
[-] ERROR: unable to start tor service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo torctl status
--==[ torctl.sh by blackarch.org ]==--

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
[!] WARNING: torctl is stopped
[!] WARNING: tor service is:
[+] torctl-autowipe service is: enabled
[+] torctl-autostart service is: enabled
```

I do not know if I could be useful but since the error is talking about PID 1, I thought providing this would not hurt anyone :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps 1 | cat
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:04 init [2]
```

Comment: What OS exactly are you running on the RasPi?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I am using Raspberry Pi OS Lite.

Comment: Which version of the PiOS?

Comment: I don't know the exact version but when typing `lsb_release -r` I get `Release:        10`